# How to resolve typescript errors in custom theme in Material UI 5?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

We have `palette.ts` which contains all color properties in `palette` variable and exported. And we imported `palette.ts` in `themeProvider.tsx` and used. But we are getting typescript error due to custom properties as following picture. Is it any way to define the type for custom properties.

`palette.ts`

```
import { alpha } from '@mui/material/styles';

const palette = {
  common: { black: '#000', white: '#fff' },
  primary: { ...PRIMARY },
  secondary: { ...SECONDARY },
  info: { ...INFO },
  success: { ...SUCCESS },
  warning: { ...WARNING },
  error: { ...ERROR },
  grey: GREY,
  gradients: GRADIENTS,
  chart: CHART_COLORS,
  divider: GREY[500_24],
  text: { primary: GREY[800], secondary: GREY[600], disabled: GREY[500] },
  background: { paper: '#fff', default: GREY[100], neutral: GREY[200] },
  action: {
    active: GREY[600],
    hover: GREY[500_8],
    selected: GREY[500_16],
    disabled: GREY[500_80],
    disabledBackground: GREY[500_24],
    focus: GREY[500_24],
    hoverOpacity: 0.08,
    disabledOpacity: 0.48,
  },
  custom: {
    iconBorderRadius: 1,
    iconBorderRadius2: 0.5,
  },
};

export default palette;
```

`themeProvider.tsx`

```
import { createTheme, CssBaseline } from '@mui/material';
import {
  StyledEngineProvider, ThemeProvider as MUIThemeProvider
} from '@mui/material/styles';
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import componentsOverride from './overrides';
import palette from './palette';
import shadows, { customShadows } from './shadows';
import typography from './typography';

export default function ThemeProvider({ children }) {
  const themeOptions = useMemo(
    () => ({
      palette,
      shape: { borderRadius: 8 },
      typography,
      shadows,
      customShadows,
    }),
    []
  );
  const theme = createTheme(themeOptions);
  theme.components = componentsOverride(theme);

  return (
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <MUIThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        {children}
      </MUIThemeProvider>
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  );
}
```

`Usage typescript error`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As mui.com says:
"If you are using TypeScript, you would also need to use module augmentation for the theme to accept the above values."

so for your case you need to add those lines to your `palette.ts`

```
interface CustomPalettes {
  custom: {
    iconBorderRadius: number;
    iconBorderRadius2: number;
  };
}
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface PaletteOptions extends CustomPalettes {}
}
declare module '@mui/material/styles/createPalette' {
  interface Palette extends CustomPalettes {}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).